# Is a logger accessible to both parent and child processes?

Tags: python, logging

In python if a logger is configured in the parent process, then will the child process also get that logger? To be more clear, in my application I configure root logger for parent process by doing `logger = logging.getlogger()` and adding handlers to it. Now when a child process is forked and it does

```
logger = logging.getlogger()
logger.info("dfsdf")
```

then all the logs are processed according to the parent's root logger. I didn't configure the root logger for the child. How is it possible? They are two different processes then how can they have same logger?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you fork a process, it 'inherits' the parent process memory, including the logger configuration.

From the [Fork Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork_%28operating_system%29):

> The fork operation creates a separate address space for the child. The child process has an exact copy of all the memory segments of the parent process, though if copy-on-write semantics are implemented actual physical memory may not be assigned (i.e., both processes may share the same physical memory segments for a while). Both the parent and child processes possess the same code segments, but execute independently of each other.

This is not unique to Python; this happens for any UNIX process that is forked, be it implemented in C, Perl or Python.

The [`multiprocessing` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html) uses this (on platforms that support it) to spin up new processes quickly.

Note that inheriting a logger may lead to race conditions; the `logging` module only knows about thread-safety; it uses a thread lock to serialize access to handlers, but that lock is not shared across processes (everything in the child process is a copy, and not the same object).

This means that when you log messages from both the parent and child at the same time, the log entries can end up mixed together as the OS switches between the two processes while writing the log entries to the file.

Comment: Thanks for clearing my doubt. Does this enable me to use parent logger directly in a child process if I want to, instead of passing it as an argument from parent to child while forking? Is it a right approach?

Comment: You can use the result of fork() to perform post-fork actions to clean up situations like this (redirecting logs) or by using a logging process with an API like log4j.

Comment: Hi can you suggest a good way to do cleanup actions after forking. This is causing a lot of problem in my code.

Comment: Set up logging after forking instead of before perhaps?

Comment: @alice: If you need cleanup after forking, and not only because of logging race conditions, probably, you do not neet forking at all. If you are just running some task in another process, and do not need that process to have full copy of you initial process' objects, use the subprocess library.

Comment: I solved my problem by checking in child process if the handler list of the logger is empty. If it is not empty, then I empty it by setting the list to [ ]. This cleans up what was inherited from parent and everything works fine. Thanks all for your replies.

Answer (score 4):

There are two things that may confuse you.

1. "The same logger object." Object is, of course, not the same, quite like all the objects in the child process are not the same as ones in the parent process. Child process is a full copy of its parent with a separate address space. That means they do not share any memory. If an object is located at some memory address in parent process, after fork the child process will have an identical object located at the same address. However, the addresses are in different address spaces, memory is not shared, and the objects are not related to each other after the forking is done. So, the short answer to your question is: the objects are not the same.
2. The logger object may have a file open before the fork is done. Open file is inherited by child process. That means the two processes have two file handles for a single file. And that is a question of synchronization.

UPD: I have looked through the logging module sources in my Python 2.7 installation. It uses `threading.RLock` to synchronize log access. That means you can not safely use the same log file in parent and child processes. You have to care about child and parent processes having different logs. Is it a daemon program? If yes, usually parent process does not need much logging and may use a separate logger.

Comment: Does `threading.RLock` support multiple processes? I feel like it shouldn't.

Comment: @m.brindley: It doesn't. The lock is copied to the child process together with everything else. Parent and child process locks do not communicate.

Comment: It's used for synchronizing threads only and does not know about other processes at all. So the logs may be corrupt.