# python logging with multiprocessing, root logger different in windows

Tags: python, windows, logging, multiprocessing, python-logging

I tried logging with multiprocessing, and found under windows, I will get different root logger in child process, but under Linux that is ok.

The test code:

main.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import logging
import multiprocessing
from mymod import func

def m_func():
    server = multiprocessing.Process(target=func, args=())
    server.start()

logger = logging.getLogger()
#print 'in global main: ', logger

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print 'in main: ', logger
    m_func()
```

mymod.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger()
# print 'in global func: ', logger

def func():
    print 'in func: ', logger
```

Under Linux, the result is:

```
in main:  <logging.RootLogger object at 0x10e4d6d90>
in func:  <logging.RootLogger object at 0x10e4d6d90>
```

But under Windows 7, 64 bit, I will get different root logger between main and func:

```
in main:  <logging.RootLogger object at 0x00000000021FFD68>
in func:  <logging.RootLogger object at 0x00000000023BC898>
```

And If I initialize root logger in main scripts, how can I keep the settings such as level in child process under windows?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems to me that this could be linked to [the following platform-dependant behaviour](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#module-multiprocessing):

> 16.6.3.2. Windows
>   Since Windows lacks os.fork() it has a few extra restrictions:
>
> (...)
>
> Global variables
>
> Bear in mind that if code run in a child process tries to access a
>   global variable, then the value it sees (if any) may not be the same
>   as the value in the parent process at the time that Process.start was
>   called.
>
> However, global variables which are just module level constants cause
>   no problems.

From your question, I assume that this results in a `logging.basicConfig()` call that is not reaching all your processes. A solution to this is to have your child processes to log to a `Queue` (using `QueueHandler`), and have a dedicated thread in your main process that will listen to the queue.

Comment: Thanks, I think this is really the reason, I have seen another similar answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/14643726/1276501 . btw, it seems that `QueueHandler` only exists in python 3.x