# OS dependent behavior with python logging module

Tags: python, logging, multiprocessing, os-dependent

Following [This question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34724643/python-logging-with-multiprocessing-root-logger-different-in-windows), I'm looking for a solution to the following problem:

I have a Python program which supposed to run both on Windows and Linux.

My python process spawns a child process, and both of them should have a file logger. I want each of them to log into their own log file.

process creation:

```
import multiprocessing
multiprocessing.Process(target=my_target, args=(my_args,))
```

log creation:

```
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger()
fh = logging.FileHandler(log_file, mode="a+")
logger.addHandler(fh)
```

In Windows it works great, but in Linux I got the child output written into both the child and parent log.

What will be the best way to deal with such a scenario?

Comment: what is `log_file` ? BTW you have to protect your multiprocessing with `if __name__ == "__main__":` on windows.

Comment: It's only a small snippet of the code. `log_file` is a path to the log file, different between child and parent process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Added the following code to solve the issue, at the beginning of execution of the chilld:

```
log = logging.getLogger()
# Remove any existing handlers
for handler in log.handlers:
    log.removeHandler(handler)
```